# Webside name for Django

Tags: python, django

I just began to write some webapplications/websides on python django. I want to know -for later-  is it possible to change the server name. I mean currently I have a server with a Ip port/adress and its Offline. My question is;

1) Is it possible to make the webside online on Internet for free or does it cost anythink?

2) Is it possible to get another servername/webadress than my current Ip for free or does it cost anythink?

I hope I asked the questions correctly and Ill be happy if I can get a answer from Community..
Have a good day

Comment: It doesn't matter you write your website using django or react.js, it have nothing in common with creating server for the site. You should read some information about sites... Buy domain name, but you have no need in hosting as you have your own 24\7 working server.

Comment: Read about backend first before django or anything else in case of not buying hosting which does a lot of stuff for you

Comment: @Alexey Its not Problem if I need to buy a domain. What I want is, a webside name which i can make him online 7/24 and writing the webside with django. Is that possible? Yeah i thought a webside and server is the same thing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your website to heroku website it is free hosting, but you need serve static file in another website like AWS S3 
Watch this
https://youtu.be/6DI_7Zja8Zc 
You can watch all the playlist in this link
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p

It is good explaining

Another solution is :
You can deploy it to Python anywhere but I am not sure if it is free

Comment: Thank you Ill watch it.